# Insert gif image to custom flex progressbar

Tags: apache-flex, progress-bar

I have created a custom progressBar by extending from flex's progressBar. I want to insert an gif image in the custom progressBar by using flex's Image but nothing happen.

Do i need to implement any flex interface? Please advice.

Thank you

```
package com
{

    import mx.controls.Image;
    import mx.controls.Label;
    import mx.controls.ProgressBar;
    import mx.core.mx_internal;

    use namespace mx_internal;


    public class CustomProgressBar extends ProgressBar
    {
        [Embed("resource/images/running_animated_gif.gif")]
        [Bindable]
        public var runningGif:Class;

        public function CustomProgressBar()
        {
            super();
        }

        override protected function createChildren():void
        {
            super.createChildren();

            var gifImage:Image = new Image();
            gifImage.source = runningGif
            addChild(gifImage);
        }

    }
}
```

Comment: Can you add some code ... what exactly you tried...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are skin properties for ProgressBar. You can apply your custom skin component to it. 
Below example may help you to add skin to your custom progressbar class.

class Name: - CustomProgressBar.as

```
package
{
    import mx.controls.ProgressBar;

    public class CustomProgressBar extends ProgressBar

    {
        public function CustomProgressBar()
        {
            super();
            this.setStyle("trackSkin", CustomProgressBarTrackSkin);
        }
    }
}
```

In your skinclass you can add image which will get displayed on your progress bar.
CustomProgressBarTrackSkin.mxml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<s:SparkSkin name="CustomProgressBarSkin"
             xmlns:fx="http://ns.adobe.com/mxml/2009"
             xmlns:s="library://ns.adobe.com/flex/spark" >

    <fx:Script>
        <![CDATA[
            override protected function initializationComplete():void {
                useChromeColor = true;
                super.initializationComplete();
            }
        ]]>
    </fx:Script>

    <!-- layer 1: fill -->
    <s:Rect left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:BitmapFill source="@Embed('resource/images/running_animated_gif.gif')" fillMode="repeat" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 2: border -->
    <s:Rect left="2" right="2" top="2" bottom="2" >
        <s:stroke>
            <s:LinearGradientStroke rotation="90">
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.9" />
                <s:GradientEntry color="0xFFFFFF" alpha="0.5" />
            </s:LinearGradientStroke>
        </s:stroke>
    </s:Rect>

    <!-- layer 3: right edge -->
    <s:Rect right="1" top="2" bottom="2" width="1" >
        <s:fill>
            <s:SolidColor color="0x000000" alpha="0.55" />
        </s:fill>
    </s:Rect>

</s:SparkSkin>
```

In the same way you can create different class for different skins ex. barSkin etc...

this may help you...